# Multiple Keywords with same name found but there is only unique keyword

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, robotframework

*When i run my robot tests it says Multiple keywords with name 'Set 
    Variable Value for' found. Give the full name of the keyword you want to use:
    step_definitions.Set Variable Value for
    variable_handler.Set Variable Value for
    It does this for all the keywords mentioned in variable_handler.py

Is there something that i am missing? Do we need to give the name 
    of python file that has that keyword?*
found not much online. have added the library in the settings.

````
    Variable_handler.py


    ```@keyword(name='Set Variable Value for')

        def Set_Variable_Value_for(tag, value):
        my_token_file = 'Resources/written_variables.yml'
        data = None
        with open(my_token_file, 'r') as testData:
            data = yaml.load(testData)
        data[tag] = value
        with open(my_token_file, 'w') as writeTestData:
            print(ruamel.yaml.dump(data, writeTestData, 
        Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper))```


    step_definitions.py



    '''@keyword(name='Set Start Time for Test')

        def Test_Start_Time():
        tz = timezone('UTC')
        Time_Now = datetime.now(tz)
        naive_date = Time_Now.replace(tzinfo=None)
        Set_Variable_Value_for('START_TIME', naive_date)```

     Test.robot



    '''Create a New Member
        [Documentation] Add a New Member
        [Tags]  CreateMember  MemberAndProjectCreationFlow  SanityTest  
       All
        Login to Platform Analytics
        Verify Member List Page Elements
        Click on Add Member
        Add Member Breadcrumb is displayed
        Add New Member Details
        Verify New Member Creation
        Search for the Member  ${NEW_MEMBER_NAME_GLOBAL}
        Search the Results and Go To  ${NEW_MEMBER_NAME_GLOBAL}  
      ${Member_Row_Locator}  ${Member_Column}
        ${MEMBER_HOMEPAGE} =  Replace String  ${MEMBER_HOME}  
     MEMBERHOME  ${NEW_MEMBER_SCHEMA_GLOBAL}
        Set Global Variable  ${MEMBER_HOMEPAGE_GLOBAL}  
      ${MEMBER_HOMEPAGE}
        Set Variable Value for  MEMBER_HOMEPAGE  ${MEMBER_HOMEPAGE}

        Log To Console  Member Creation Successful.```
````

It should work without specifying the python file that contains 
    the key word. I have imported all the things required like variable_handler and step definitions

Comment: The formatting of your question makes it very hard to read. Please try to use code formatting only for the code.

Answer (score 7):

The root of the matter is that you have two or more keywords with the same name imported into the test. When you try to run the keyword `Set Variable Value for`, robot doesn't know which of the keywords to run. It has no way of knowing if the two names represent two different functions or the same function in two different libraries.

You have three possible solutions:

1. As the error suggests, you can specify the full path to the keyword, such as `step_definitions.Set Variable Value`
2. You tell robot to give precedence to one library over the other using the built-in keyword [Set Library Search Order](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Library%20Search%20Order).
3. You can modify your libraries so that you don't have duplicate keyword names

For more information see [Handling keywords with same names](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id628) in the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).